# How to generate Array of items in html template for creating pdf in Node Js?

Tags: html, arrays, node.js, pdf, dynamic

I am using [html-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf) for pdf creation on my project. i can generate all the details into the pdf. but the thing is i can not be able to create List of items in array in html(which will be used for pdf conversion). 
 
               Since i cannot use javascript to get the array of items, i am unable to get it. if there is a tweak to use javascript in html template,please post it here. Since the array of items is known, i can use it easily.  
Suppose if the array length is 3 . i can use like `array[0].name ,array[1].name, array[2].name` but here i don't know the length of the array which consists of how many items. Can anyone please help me here to generate the table of items which is generating dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use *Javascript* in template, but you can use *Javascript* on it.

The idea is to make a parser which will :

- **read your template**
- **replace a keywork** (for example : `<customTable arrayName="myCustomArray" fields="['name']" />`) with a generated HTML array in *Node.js*.
- **use this template** with *html-parser*.

I write an example of parser in *VanillaJS* here : https://jsfiddle.net/rbuuzcre/5/

Comment: Thanks for your help, can you update fiddle with 4 columns in the table. please

Comment: If you want to add columns, you just need to add some fields in array.